# Implement badge notification on my app

Tags: iphone, notifications

I am new to iphone Notification. In my app, I am displaying RSS Feed contents and whenever changes happening in server side of RSS Feeds, then I want to show the notification on top of application icon with number badge and also this number should be based on number of feeds changed ( This is changes may be a Addition/Deletion/updates of RSS Feeds). Now, I trying to learn notification with some online resources, but I am not able to follow that.Please guide me? is there any sample due to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read the [Apple developer guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) to the topic?

There is a server backend component to remote push notifications that you'll need to develop/host too. You can outsource the infrastructure to companies like [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/products/push/) or [iLime](http://www.ilime.com/push-notification/) to do that part for you. Urban Airship have a [sample project](http://bitbucket.org/urbanairship/push_sample/) available that uses them.